# The model mistakes everything it knew from its pre-trained model as my custom object

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, transfer-learning

I've followed an object detection tutorial from pythonprogramming.net to recognize a small robot (my custom object) based on the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco model.

I've about 450 labelled images of my robot.

I used the official sample config for ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco, and only made the necessary changes like num_class = 1, and reduced the batch size to 7, and trained until I had a loss that was consistently between 1 and 2 (about 10000 epochs).

The problem is, the model detects everything it used to know from its pre-trained state as my small robot. So it identifies everything as being a robot even though they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before. And fixed it by adding images contains pre-trained objects as negative examples. Another way to fix it is training longer. If you do both that will fix the problem i think. And try increasing your dataset by the way (i was training with 6000 images).

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Training longer might not work because even after 20k steps, it detects everything as robots with 99% accuracy. So I'll try the other approach.

Can you briefly explain how you configured the other objects as negative examples? You don't have to give a detailed answer. But I'd greatly appreciate some guidance.
I know I'll need the original COCO dataset, and edit their annotations... And then not include them on my label-map.pbtxt... Am I understanding correctly?
Thanks again, I'm under some stress and really need to get this done.